# Swift: iOS Paypal response parsing into NSDictionary/NSArray

Tags: json, xcode, swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm using PayPal sdk with Xcode for iOS

I managed to work with it successfully. Now, I have the following response from the server:

Code:

```
self.resultText = completedPayment.confirmation
println(self.resultText)
```

Result:

```
[response: {
"create_time" = "2015-07-13T17:52:31Z";
id = "PAY-NONETWORKPAYIDEXAMPLE123";
intent = sale;
state = approved;
}, 

client: {
environment = mock;
"paypal_sdk_version" = "2.11.1";
platform = iOS;
"product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
}, 

response_type: payment]
```

My question is that, I just want to parse and access all the data results into NSDictionary and/or NSArray

Comment: @KLD, Did you want to get all data from the response and clinet, Is it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved it in this way...

```
let paymentResultDic = completedPayment.confirmation as NSDictionary


        let dicResponse: AnyObject? = paymentResultDic.objectForKey("response")
        println(dicResponse!.objectForKey("create_time"))
        println(dicResponse!.objectForKey("id"))
        println(dicResponse!.objectForKey("intent"))
        println(dicResponse!.objectForKey("state"))

        let dicClient: AnyObject? = paymentResultDic.objectForKey("client")
        println(dicClient!.objectForKey("environment"))
        println(dicClient!.objectForKey("paypal_sdk_version"))
        println(dicClient!.objectForKey("platform"))
        println(dicClient!.objectForKey("product_name"))

        println(paymentResultDic.objectForKey("response_type"))
```

if anybody has better solution, lets share it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

swift 3

```
        let paymentResultDic = completedPayment.confirmation as NSDictionary

        let dicResponse: AnyObject? = paymentResultDic.object(forKey: "response") as AnyObject?
        let paycreatetime:String = dicResponse!["create_time"] as! String
        let payauid:String = dicResponse!["id"] as! String
        let paystate:String = dicResponse!["state"] as! String
        let payintent:String = dicResponse!["intent"] as! String


        print("id is  --->%@",payauid)
        print("created  time ---%@",paycreatetime)
        print("paystate is ----->%@",paystate)
        print("payintent is ----->%@",payintent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Pod `SwiftyJSON` like this:

```
    let data = payment.confirmation as NSDictionary
    var jsonObj = JSON(data)

    // For the response part
    let response = jsonObj["response"]
    let id = response["id"].stringValue
    let intent = response["intent"].stringValue
    let create_time = response["create_time"].stringValue
    let state = response["state"].stringValue

    // For the client part
    let client = jsonObj["client"]
    let environment = client["environment"].stringValue
    let paypal_sdk_version = client["paypal_sdk_version"].stringValue
    let platform = client["platform"].stringValue
    let product_name = client["product_name"].stringValue

    // For the response type
    let response_type = jsonObj["response_type"].stringValue
```